# Invalid element type: expecting a string or class function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having an issue rendering my code. I have wrapped my app with my Provider class but I keep getting an error on the browser.

Below is what my App.js looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import axios from 'axios';

import teamContext from "../contexts/teamContext";
import TeamList from "./TeamList";
import TeamForm from "./TeamForm";

const initialState = {
  teamList: [],
  teamForm: {
    name: "",
    age: "",
    height: "",
    id: "",
  }
}

class Provider extends React.Component {
  state = initialState;

  render() {
    return (
      <teamContext.Provider value={{

        state: this.state,

        getMembers: () => {
          axios.get('http://localhost:3000/smurfs')
            .then(res => {
              console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
          })
        }
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </teamContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <Provider className="App">
          <TeamList />
          <TeamForm />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root"));

export default App;
```

and this is the exact error message:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of Provider.
```

Answer (score 0):

At initial glance of the code, seems like you should rename your `teamContext` from camel case to use sentence case `TeamContext`.

You might already know this from reactjs.org:

> **Note:** Always start component names with a capital letter.
>
> React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags.
>   For example, `<div />` represents an HTML div tag, but `<Welcome />` represents a component and requires `Welcome` to be in scope.